# Trying to do a simple fraction with ViewController though stumped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I keep on getting 0/0 for my answer in the view.
I'm not sure why it's not updating?
I'm sure someone out there will have a quick look and solve it in a flash. I'm a total beginner so I'm stumped.

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction
{
    #pragma mark --Step#3---What are the variables
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

}


-(void) setNumerator: (int) setNumerator
{
    #pragma mark --Step#8---Make sure the setter is on the right
    /*  I had these back to front before  */
     NSLog (@"setNumerator %d ", setNumerator);
    setNumerator = numerator;

}
-(void) setDenominator: (int) setDenominator
{
     NSLog (@"setDenominator %d ", setDenominator);
    setDenominator = denominator;

}
#pragma mark --Step#2---Copy over the methods and set them up
-(NSString*)print
{

    NSString* calStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i/%i ",numerator,denominator];
    return calStr;
}

@end
```

After implementing the @property(assign) /*  in interface .h  */
from @Anoop Vaidya  Thank you! :)

the header looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject
#pragma mark --Step#1---What are the methods
/*  what is this program going to do?*/
@property (assign) NSInteger numerator; //NSInteger is typedef to int
@property (assign) NSInteger denominator;
-(NSString*)print;
@end
```

and the .h file:

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction


/*  don't need these with the @property (assign) */
//-(void) setNumerator: (int) setNumerator
//{
//    #pragma mark --Step#8---Make sure the setter is on the right
//    /*  I had these back to front before  */
//     NSLog (@"setNumerator %d ", setNumerator);
//    _numerator = setNumerator;
//   
//}
//-(void) setDenominator: (int) setDenominator
//{
//     NSLog (@"setDenominator %d ", setDenominator);
//    _denominator = setDenominator;
//   
//}
#pragma mark --Step#2---Copy over the methods and set them up
-(NSString*)print
{

    NSString* calStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i/%i ",_numerator,_denominator];
    return calStr;
}

@end
```

Comment: How can I share files like this @MatthiasBauch?

Comment: @GerardGrundy You should copy/paste relevant pieces of your code directly into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
setNumerator = numerator;
```

and

```
setDenominator = denominator;
```

do it other way:

```
numerator = setNumerator;
```

and

```
denominator = setDenominator;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to bring few things to you information (as you seems to be learning):

```
-(void) setNumerator: (int) setNumerator;
```

Is a very bad method name, against the Apple naming conventions. It should be as :

```
-(void)numerator: (int)aNumerator;
```

Also you did a reverse assignment here:

```
-(void) numerator: (int)aNumerator{
    numerator = aNumerator;       
}
```

Instead of creating in implementation, these two:

```
int numerator;
int denominator;
```

You should have created it in interface as:

```
@interface Fraction : NSObject

@property (assign) NSInteger numerator; //NSInteger is typedef to int
@property (assign) NSInteger denominator;

@end
```

As this would crate setter and getter for you, so no need to create explicitly as you did.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to do the : property (assign) numerator;
property (assign) denominator; though I don't understand where to put it?

Comment: I'm trying ----interface Fraction()

    property (assign) numerator;
    property (assign) denominator;

end ---sorry I can't add the @ symbol as it creates errors in stack overflow

Comment: @GerardGrundy: Put `@property` after `@interface Fraction : NSObject` updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that and got this error--> 
Type name requires a specifier or qualifier

Comment: @GerardGrundy: ooopsss, my bad, please see the update